# Google Maps API strange behavior with wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using this example code to put a google map in a wordpress page:

```
<div id="map"  style="height:300px; width:300px;"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I filled my api_key properly.
So, maps loads, but some problems happens like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOfEO.png) shows:

- Zoom buttons and street view "doll" change to strange appearance.
- All map is loaded, but if I drag for right, new area appears nothing 
  (brown opaque). If I drag to left, all appears normal. If I change zoom in opaque area, it does get back to normal, but right side problem continue.

I think problem is with wordpress, because I made same test in my local computer in a simple html page and all works.

Thank you!!

Comment: It is not WordPress problem, 100%. Deactivate all plugins, switch to standard (for instance, Twenty Seventeen) theme and you will see the map working.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Problem was in a class .markup-format, from my theme. I fixed adding  
   .markup-format img {
      max-width: none !important;
   }
in my css file. Thank you